# fastest way to copy relative link in github?

Tags: javascript, github

Our team is using github, sometime I want to show my code in a page to my colleague. Says it's `app/src/abc.ts`, I have to go to my github repo, click through the folder. Is there anyway I can do this faster?

Answer (score 1):

just type `t` on github website (to activate the file finder) and then start typing the name of the file "abc.ts" or add/paste/write the full file path

you will then get a result list like:

[image]

You can find a full list of shortcuts on [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/using-github/keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: search in github?

Comment: @alice_morgan you added the github tag so yes

Comment: I use copy relative path in vscode, I got the link I paste it in the browser, it's easier

Comment: @alice_morgan relative path is good! did you try to just hit `t` the you should get the view as in the picture above and the paste your path ...?